# Which scientists have managed to name their laws/terms after themselves?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, history

It would be pretty vain for someone to name a scientific law, unit, or term after themselves.

"Newtons" as the name for the measurement of force, for example, was adopted in 1948, so I don't expect he had much of a say in that himself.

On the other hand, I note that Ohm's Law uses omega [in the original text](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=29gPAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA182) and (although I admit I don't actually read German so I'm not entirely sure it refers to resistance as I understand it) this seems like a sneaky sort of invitation. I have noticed other occations where the choices for the names of variables was suspiciously "appropriate".

Perhaps this is a silly question, perhaps hopelessly off topic, but I'm curious for the sake of it: which scientists have managed to attach their *own* names to their laws? (i.e. from the outset, not decided later by independent consensus.)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think this is an interesting question that fits perfectly well into the history tag.

Comment: There was a story floating around the University of Pennsylvania that Herb Callen purposefully gave the fluctuation-dissipation theorem lots of syllables in the hope that in practice it would be renamed "Callen-Welton theorem".  It didn't work out for him.  I can't verify the story, but I heard it from close friends of Callen.

Comment: That's a lovely science history question. I never thought about the possibility, but I would be delighted to hear some anecdotal evidence.

Comment: @Qmechanic why does the history tag exist if this is off topic?